# Pentaho data source access from Groovy

Tags: groovy, pentaho

In Pentaho Report Designer (PRD), I want to connect to my Data source using a Groovy script (or EMCAScript script) by referring to JNDI created in default.properties file. So, I will create a mult-value list parameter containing JNDI names and connect to the data source based on the JNDI selected in the parameter.

Script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import javax.naming.InitialContext
import javax.sql.DataSource

class SqlClient {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext()
    DataSource dataSource = context.lookup("OLTP") as DataSource
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute("SELECT * FROM Person.User_JNDI")
    TypedTableModel model = new TypedTableModel();   
    while(sql.next())  
    model.addRow(new Object [] {rs.getString(1)});    
    c.close();  
    return model;
}
```

I am getting the following error:
**Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
expression: 11: unexpected token: sql @ line 11, column 5.
       sql.execute("SELECT * FROM Person.User_JNDI")**

Also, PRD expects the script to return a model, probably something to do with TypedtableModel class.

Can anyone give me an example of Groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have filled the `default.properties` as it says [here](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freport_designer_user_guide%2Ftask_jndi_data_source.html), you should be able to access the data source with something like:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

import javax.naming.InitialContext
import javax.sql.DataSource

class SqlClient {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext()
    DataSource dataSource = context.lookup("SampleData") as DataSource
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute '''
       select * from ... '''
    ...
}
```

Using a [Sql](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) instance.

Comment: Thanks @mschonaker. I added the script above adding the query (select 1) just to check whether it's connecting to the data source specified by the JNDI. But when I click okay in Pentaho report designer (PRD), it does nothing. I selected Groovy script under "Global Scripting" tab in "JDBC Data Source" window. How do I check whether it's connected successfully to the JNDI specified?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to connect to my data source using jndi in my groovy script? I used the script given above but when I click on OK button, the button just turns blue and nothing really happens.                                                My requirement is to Change the data of the report when the user selects desired JNDI in the report parameter list. So, I will have a parameter containing JNDI names and access this parameter in my Groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the following:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import javax.naming.InitialContext
import javax.sql.DataSource
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.util.TypedTableModel
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.connections.JndiDataSourceService

JndiDataSourceService jdss = new JndiDataSourceService()
DataSource dataSource = jdss.getDataSource("INSERT_DATASOURCE_NAME")

def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def rows = sql.rows '''
    select 1 from dual
'''
TypedTableModel model = new TypedTableModel();    
if(rows.size()>0)
    for (columnEntry in rows[0].entrySet()){
        def name = columnEntry.getKey()
        def type = columnEntry.getValue().getClass()
        model.addColumn(name,type)
    }

for (row in rows)
    model.addRow(row.values().toArray())  


sql.close();  
return model;
```